# Cropping Images Based Off The Location of the Head

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, geometry, emgucv

I'm looking to crop an image by finding the head and shoulders. The aspect ratio I'm looking for is 3.5/4.5.

Like this:

[image]

Yet this is an example result from my code:

[image]

This is my code, but each and every time it's just super zoomed into the forehead or hair. Nothing I do is working to crop the image like the illustration image.

```
public string CropPortraitPhoto(string originalPath)
{
    try
    {
        // Load the image.
        Mat image = Cv2.ImRead(originalPath);

        if (image.Empty())
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load image.");
        }

        // Convert the image to grayscale for face detection.
        Mat grayImage = new Mat();
        Cv2.CvtColor(image, grayImage, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);

        // Detect faces in the image with adjusted parameters.
        using (CascadeClassifier faceCascade = new CascadeClassifier(Server.MapPath("/py/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")))
        {
            Cv2.SetNumThreads(1); // Disable multi-threading for this function
            Cv2.SetUseOptimized(false);

            Rect[] faces = faceCascade.DetectMultiScale(grayImage, 1.1, 5, HaarDetectionType.ScaleImage, new Size(30, 30));

            //if (faces.Length == 0)
            //{
            //    throw new Exception("No faces detected.");
            //}

            // Find the face with the largest area (most confident detection).
            Rect selectedFace = faces.OrderByDescending(f => f.Width * f.Height).First();

            // Calculate the head and shoulders area based on the specified rules.
            int headHeight = (int)(selectedFace.Height * 0.85); // Adjust this value for better results.
            int headY = selectedFace.Y + (selectedFace.Height - headHeight) / 2;

            // Calculate shoulder area based on dimensions
            int shoulderHeight = (int)(headHeight * 0.5); // Adjust this value based on your requirements.
            int shoulderY = headY + headHeight;

            // Calculate the target width and height in pixels based on the specified aspect ratio and resolution
            double aspectRatio = 35.0/45.0;
            int targetHeight = (int)(aspectRatio * headHeight);

            // Calculate crop position and size to show the full head and shoulders
            int x = selectedFace.X + (selectedFace.Width - targetHeight) / 4;
            int y = headY - headHeight + 20; // Adjust the padding from the top

            // Adjust crop position and size if necessary
            if (x < 0) x = 0;
            if (y < 0) y = 0;
            if (x + targetHeight > image.Width) x = image.Width - targetHeight;
            if (y + targetHeight > image.Height) y = image.Height - targetHeight;

            // Calculate cropped area
            Rect croppedArea = new Rect(x, y, targetHeight, targetHeight);

            // Crop the image to the calculated area.
            Mat croppedImage = new Mat(image, croppedArea);

            // Resize the cropped image to the UK passport size
            Mat resizedImage = new Mat();
            Cv2.Resize(croppedImage, resizedImage, new Size(350, 450));

            // Generate a web-friendly file name
            string uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".jpg";
            string webName = "/results/" + uniqueFileName;

            // Save the cropped and resized image.
            string outputPath = Server.MapPath(webName);
            Cv2.ImWrite(outputPath, resizedImage);

            // Return the web-friendly file name.
            return webName;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions and return an error message if needed.
        return "Error: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: was this code generated by AI? what is your understanding of the code you present? have you visualized all the bounding boxes that show up in the code? what steps have you taken to debug it? [mre]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, the comments were generated by AI. The code itself wasn't, no. I've managed to adjust the settings to make it slightly better, however, still not great. I've debugged through adjusting the settings.